# Href no redirige en versión mobile. Si funciona en desktop

Tags: javascript, html, programación-móvil

Estoy realizando una página multilenguaje. Para lo cual tengo un `<a href="#">` que me redireccioná a la página en inglés o en español usando JavaScript respectivamente.

Este es un ejemplo de la lógica que utilizo. Si lo pruebo en mi computadora funciona sin problemas, pero en celulares (Por ejemplo utilizando chrome versión mobile) no redirecciona. Osea vuelve a cargar la pagina pero en ningún momento modifica el link.

Ejemplo: si el url es index.html al apretar en "Inglés" tendría que cambiar a `index.html/#ingles`. No obstante si mantengo apretado y lo abro en una pestaña nueva, esta nueva si viene con el `tag` incluido.

```
<a href="#espanol" data-reload> Espanol </a>
<br>
<a href="#ingles" data-reload> Ingles </a>
<h4 id=a>titulo</h4>

<script>
    var dataReload = document.querySelectorAll("[data-reload]");
    var lenguaje = {
        espanol: {
            titulo: "titulo"
        },
        ingles: {
            titulo: "title"
        }
    }

    if(window.location.hash){
        if(window.location.hash === "#espanol"){
            a.textContent = lenguaje.espanol.titulo;
        } 
    }

    if(window.location.hash){
        if(window.location.hash === "#ingles"){
            a.textContent = lenguaje.ingles.titulo;
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<=dataReload.length; i++){
        dataReload[i].onclick = function(){
            window.location.reload(true);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Alguna idea? Muchas gracias por su tiempo. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mira creo que se te ha olvidado añadir el hash antes de recargar la pagina

```
 for(let i=0; i<dataReload.length; i++){
        dataReload[i].onclick = function(){
            window.location.hash = dataReload[i].hash;
            window.location.reload(true);
        }
    }
```

creo que eso causa que se recargue sin ningún hash, podrías añadir la siguiente linea antes de llamar a la función reload añadiendo el hash que necesites:

```
window.location.hash = dataReload[i].attr("href");
```

Comment: Hola ontimond! Gracias por contestar, te hago hago una consulta porque no pude terminar de entender tu propuesta ya que soy muy nuevo en esto. A que te referis con "Añadiendo el hash que necesite" Yo estoy copiando y pegando eso que me pasaste y no funciono, probe con poner  dataReload[i].attr("#en"); o  dataReload[i].attr("#es"); y tampoco funciono, debo estar haciendo algo mal pero no llego a entender que. La pagina en version desktop funciona sin problema es solo que en celular no quiere agregar en el url el #es o #en respectivamente luego de hacer reload (Que si lo hace)
Saludos y gracias

Comment: Estuve analizando un poco el código y encontré varios problemas en el bucle, bueno eran pequeño pero hay que mencionarlos, no declaraste la variable **i** por lo tanto generara un error al asignar el evento onclick, el siguiente problema es que en la condición del for deber solamente mientras sea menor **<**, y en cuanto al hash intento obtener el hash de las etiquetas de hyperlink **<a>** que declaraste, añadiré una corrección en el código puesto que **dataReload[i].attr("href");** no funciono, debes cambiarlo por **window.location.hash = dataReload[i].hash;**

Comment: Wow muchisimas gracias! Hice lo que me dijiste y funciona perfecto! Muchisimas gracias por tu tiempo, Saludos!!!! :D

Answer (score 0):

Si cambias el código

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

Por

```
SetTimeout(location.reload.bind(location), 1);
```

Funciona de la forma que quieres.

Sin embargo es un poco extraño ese comportamiento que buscas, dado que la idea del hash es justamente no recargar la página.
Si realmente quieres recargar podrías utilizar dos páginas /en y /es con links usuales o querystrings `ejemplo.html?lang=es`.

Comment: Hola Sebastian, muchas gracias por tu tiempo, realice lo que me propusiste pero dejo de funcionar en la versión desktop. 
Luego en base a lo que me propones, en un principio había hecho como decís, tener dos index, uno por cada idioma pero eso no me complicaría el mantenimiento ya que cada vez que modifico algo a nivel estructura tendría que estar copiando y pegando el trabajo en todos los archivos que tenga en otro idioma.
Esta logica la saque de una pagina que encontré, soy bastante nuevo en JavaScript y uso de Hashes.
Saludos